# d3.svg.line stroke is skewed when scaling y-dimension with SVG transform

Tags: svg, d3.js

Using d3's `d3.svg.line` produces a line which looks after magnifying **only** in the y-dimension like this one
[image: line segment]

Here is the corresponding path element

```
<path d="M 70.13775,
    303.1818181818182 L 73.03775,
    285.9090909090909 L 75.93775,
    402.5 L 78.83775,
    402.5 L 81.73775,
    419.77272727272725 L 84.63775,
    342.0454545454545 L 87.53775"></path>
```

As one can see, when the pen is moved to the right, the width of the corresponding line segment is a different one compared to the width of the line of the path segment, when the pen is moved vertically.

*Question*: Is it possible to draw the line  in a such way that the width of line is the same everywhere? As if one draws the line with holding a pen with a round brush perpendicular to the drawing area.

Comment: Are you scaling the path? Looks fine to me http://jsfiddle.net/T74NA/

Comment: @LarsKotthoff: Yes, I am magnifying the whole picture a lot. -- Oh, stupid. I am scaling only y-axis, but not the x-axis. That's the problem. I still don't have any solution.

Comment: Scale both dimensions then. If you want to spread out the points, you can modify the data accordingly.

Comment: The solution is to set the attribute `vector-effect` to `non-scaling-stroke`, cf. http://www.w3.org/TR/SVGTiny12/painting.html#NonScalingStroke.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to scale your line along one axis, instead of using an svg transform you would probably be better off using a `d3.scale` to scale your incoming data when you make your `d3.svg.line()`.

Lets say you have a d3 scale called `myScale`

Then when you make your d3 svg line, you can use the scale to modify one of the coordinates:

```
var lineGen = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function(d) {return d.x;})
  .y(function(d) {return myScale(d.y);});
```

The solution of using `vector-effect` will probably give you the result you want in bleeding edge browsers, but it seems like overkill to use an effect to do something this simple, and the lack of browser support for SVG1.2 features might become problematic for you. If you were trying to fix a static svg file that would probably be the way to go, but since you are generating it with d3, you might as well use the built-in methods for scaling.

**EDIT**

For a simpler solution, you could even scale it by a constant factor:

```
var scaleFactor = 1.75;
var lineGen = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function(d) {return d.x;})
  .y(function(d) {return d.y * scaleFactor;});
```